# Storing enum to MongoDb (for managing tag names)

Tags: mongodb

If we have a collection of books, we can assign tags of authors into an array as follows:

*Books collection*

```
{
    ...,
    "authors" : ["John Michaels", "Bill Williams"]
}
```

This can cause **problems if an author's name changes**.

Instead, I was thinking of **assigning an integer value to each author** and creating a 'tags' collection:

*Tags collection*

```
{
    “tags” : [
        {“John Michaels” : 0},
        {“Jane Collins” : 1},
        {“Bill Williams” : 2}
    ]
}
```

Here is my *books collection*, here we specify that ‘John Michaels’ and ‘Bill Williams’ are the authors:

```
{
    …,
    “authors” : [0, 2]
}
```

If I ever needed to change the author’s name ‘Bill Williams’ to ‘Bill H. Williams’, there would be no problem because the value stored in the books collection remains unchanged.

My Question is if MongoDB has something like enums that will automatically increment the integral value or if there is something else built into MongoDB to help with this type of situation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical use case of referencing other collections. So, you should have 2 collections:

**Authors collection:**

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  ... // Other fields
}
```

**Books collection:**

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  authors: [ ObjectId ], // References to documents from Author collection
  ... // Other fields
}
```

So, in `authors` property of the **Books** collection, you store `_id` values of all the authors. Then when you fetch **book** document, you can easily fetch up-to-date `authors` data from **Authors** collection.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and thank you!  What is your opinion regarding your answer for highly generic tags used for articles?  Do you think that using strings or documents is the better choice?  The simpler choice of course is strings, but I think that this can lead to different junk and duplicate tag names being used.  I don't know if the object idea would be worth the effort.  What you do think?

Comment: A quick example would be that someone entered the tag 'bussiness' and people have been using it.  Then you go and edit it correctly it to 'business'.  Prior articles will use the misspelled tag.

Comment: You can also create `Tag` collection, and `tags` property in `Article` collection that would store `_id` value of all the `tags` from `Tag` collection.